# How to implement route-based code splitting when using useRoutes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Am trying to find a way of implementing route-based code-splitting, I tried lazy loading the components and wrap the component in suspense. Still, it resulted in only several components being successfully split from the main bundle and bu not all.

```
function AppRoutes() {
      const routes = useRoutes(
        [
          {path:'/',
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><Login/></Suspense>)},
          {path:'signup',
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><Signup/></Suspense>)},
          {path="about", 
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><About/></Suspense>) }
          {path="contact", 
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><Contact /></Suspense>)}
          {path="customers", 
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><Customers /></Suspense>)}
          {path="loans", 
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><Loans /></Suspense>}
          {path="stats", 
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><Statistics /></Suspense>}
          {path="dashboard", 
           element:(<Suspense fallback={<Loading size={45} />}><Dashboard/></Suspense> }
        ]
      )
      return routes;
    }
```

Comment: Am lazing loading the components like this`const Contact=lazy(()=>import('./components/Contact'));
const Customers=lazy(()=>import('./components/Customers'));
const Dashboard=lazy(()=>import('./components/Dashboard'));
const Home=lazy(()=>import('./components/Home'));
const Loans=lazy(()=>import('./components/Loans'));
const Statistics=lazy(()=>import('./components/Statistics'));
const About=lazy(()=>import('./components/About'));`

Answer (score 0):

Use lazy loading for the components. It should not be nothing special

```
const Login = lazy(() => import('./Login').then(component => component))
```

That will split the file where you are calling useRoute into small chunks